# using dotenv module in nodejs and typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dotenv

i create a file by this name `.env` :

```
DATABASE_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/Fimstan'
SERVER_PORT=3000
```

now i want to use that in the `app.ts` for using the `SERVER_PORT` .

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

 app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server Run On Port ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

but it show me this message in terminal : `Server Run On Port undefined`

now whats the problem ? how can  i use the `.env` content in my project ???

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import http from 'http';
import Logger from './core/logger/logger';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import passport from 'passport';
import cors from 'cors';
import redisClient from 'redis';
import path from 'path';
import configuration from './config/index';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

process.on('uncaughtException', (e) => {
  Logger.error(e);
});

dotenv.config();


const app: express.Application = express();


app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server Run On Port ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Hello')
})

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(configuration.databaseConfig.url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});


app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser("SchoolManagerSecretKey"));
```

Comment: Try `import dotenv from 'dotenv';` before calling .config() on it? Or `import { config } from 'dotenv';` and then only calling `config()`.

Comment: @timotgl  not worked

Comment: Maybe dotenv can't find your `.env` file. Try to explicitly tell it where the file is located: `config({ path: resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });` (in this example it is one directory higher up). Edit: you nedd `import { resolve } from 'path';` for this.

Comment: @timotgl still not worked

Comment: That's all I can think of, sorry. If the file looks like you posted above, and it is actually named `.env` (no hidden file extension interference from OS), then you tried the correct way to load it. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: Maybe post your directory structure, or give us a hint where this `.env` file is.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure that you set the important parts correctly for this to work.
That is why I will ignore the rest of your imports and app logic. Try to test the solution I described separately to check if this solves your problem.

1. Make sure that on your root project folder you have the package.json file and .env file.
2. In the terminal in the path to the root project folder write 'npm i dotenv' (note: it already containing the definitions you required in Typescript).
3. Now to the files:

```
    // root/.env

    SERVER_PORT=3000
    
    // root/app.ts
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';
    dotenv.config();
    console.log(`Server Run On Port ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
```

Also, note that you get the type (string | undefined) when doing an assignment from process.env.variableName.
(I am assuming that you are working with the latest versions of node, dotenv and typescript but I don't think there is much if any a difference in older versions).